# How do i write a json rule(validation) for the following schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have the following schema, so if i have more than one checkbox selected, i want to set the value of a hidden variable called peril. How do i write a rule for that The json is below

```
{
                        "path": [
                            "General",
                            "fire"
                        ],
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": true,
                        "label": "Fire"

                    },
                    {
                        "path": [
                            "General",
                            "Smoke"
                        ],
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                        "label": "Smoke"

                    },
{
                        "path": [
                            "General",
                            "Wind"
                        ],
                        "type": "boolean",
                        "default": false,
                        "label": "Wind"

                    }
```

If Fire and Smoke are selected then the value of peril should be FR,SM.. How do i write a if else validation rule in jsonSchema?

Comment: Rather than posting the same question again, edit your existing question to fix errors in your question or provide updated information.

Comment: Its a different issue altogether. The contents might be the same but the question is different. I want to set the value of a input hidden variable in a rule in JsonSchema based on user selections

Comment: Any form generation is unrealted to JSON Schema the specification. You'll have to look at the documentation for the specific library in mind. Generating UI from JSON Schema is non-standard. Sorry I can't be of any further help.